# Who was the first to awaken the Mangekyo Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

I read the news and saw people say it was Uchiha Itachi who was the first to awaken the Mangekyo Sharingan.

[image: nả]

Is it true?

Comment: Hi, could you clarify the source for the news and also what did it really say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the first to ever awaken the mangekyō you Sharingan was Madera Uchiha which is actually one of the founders of the hidden leaf village. This can be shown in the episode "Truth" (真実, Shinjitsu) in episode 141 of the Naruto: Shippūden anime. [Madara Uchiha](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha) awakened his Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan by taking his brothers' eyes and implanting them in his own.